# PyTorch) How to improve the inference speed in this case?

Tags: performance, pytorch, divide-and-conquer, inference

Can you tell me how to improve the inference speed in this case?

W = torch.rand(768, 768)
X = torch.rand(128, 128, 768)

I want to use only the 2nd and 4th quadrants of W for matrix multiplication.
(1st and 3rd quadrants of W consist of 0)

For example, i calculate this example.
X[:, :, :384] = X[:, :, :384].matmul(W[0:384, 0:384])
X[:, :, 384:768] = X[:, :, 384:768].matmul(W[384:768, 384:768])

By using this code, I tried to improve general XW matrix multiplication.
But if i use this code, inference speed is degraded..
How to implement this situation efficiently?

Additionally, Is there any "Divide-and-Conquer" library in Pytorch?

Help me please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.